# Appending values from a child class to parent class

Tags: php, oop

I have a file e.g. class.php with following code:

```
//class.php 
class main_class { 

public $output;

public function print_me ( $msg ){
$this->output .= $msg.'\r\n' ;
}

//….
//….
//more functions
// some of them using this->print_me 

} 

class sub_class extends main_class { 

function verification (){ 
this->print_me ( 'Log: while verification' );
}

}
//class.php ends
```

I need to initiate main_class in main.php file, code of main.php file is as follows

```
 //main.php 
require 'class.php';
    $main_class = new main_class();
    //and need to append values into output variables
$main_class->print_me ( 'Log: from main.php ' );
//but before echoing , I need to initiate sub class as follows:
//$sub_class = new $sub_class();
//though I do not need to append/ values using $sub_class instance , 
//I need to append value from within the class itself at last I can print output variable e.g. 
echo $main_class->output;
```

later I knew , class sub_class code is wrong , so changed from

```
function verification (){ 
this->print_me ( 'Log: while verification' );
}
```

to

```
function verification (){ 
parent::print_me ( 'Log: while verification' );
}
```

but this does not work either , I fail to append values into main_class's output variable so that i can print at last all of logs

Comment: Missing `$` sigin in verification method? Should be `$this->print_me()`.

Comment: Stick with method 1 but put the `$` infront of `$this->print_me(....)` Subclasses have automatic access to parent class properties as if they were their own. The only problem was the missing `$` and that you must be running with `display_errors` turned off, as that should have generated a compile error.

Comment: missing '$' was a typo here only, even prefixing $ fail to append values together into parent class, as I guess because of different instances , however, I was thinking what if I have a totally separate third class containing only print_me function and output variable  and somehow I call it in all classes and in objects too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have to use like this

```
$sub_class = new sub_class();
$sub_class->verification ( 'Log: from main.php 1 ' );
$sub_class->verification ( 'Log: from main.php 2 ' );
echo $sub_class->output;
```

just use the subclass object to get the log.

main class object could not return you any thing due to polymorphism.

Comment: As you say, there would be whole lot change in my script , perhaps I had to go through 10,000 lines of codes to change this way, better I find a solution to append value from sub_class only , its very small class and I had to change only few lines.